# How can I make a buffer in device(or constant) address space?

Tags: swift, constants, shader, device, metal

Metal has two major address spaces, **device** and **constant**.
And these are used like this in a shader function.

```
void foo(device int *data [[buffer(0)]]) { ... }
void bar(constant int *data [[buffer(0)]]) { ... }
```

I can understand what they are. But I cannot understand how to make them.
How to make **a buffer in device(or constant) address space**?

At first, I assume that `MTLDevice.makeBuffer(length:options:)` will do it.
But it doesn't. There are no options for **device or constant address space**.

I am confused. What did I miss?

Thank you.
Sincerely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is: you can't create a `constant` `MTLBuffer` and you don't need to. You can bind any `MTLBuffer` as a `constant` or `device` memory.

Long answer: `constant` is kind of like a hint to compiler. It tells the compiler that the data in that buffer is going to be read-only, but not exactly as in `const` sense.

There's a WWDC video from 2016 where this is discussed, here's a link with a timestamp: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc16/606?time=272

I think, this is the key point from the video:

> [...] this is the address space that's optimized for cases with a lot of data reuse. So you want to take advantage of this address space whenever it makes sense.

But I do suggest watching that part of the presentation to learn more.

Comment: Thank you for the video link. I just watched the whole video twice. Great. Really thanks.